# How to determine if a user's session has expired

Tags: node.js, session, express, express-session

I am using `express-session` and have a helper function that my route middleware are all calling, which actually does a check for a property on the `req.session` object and sends a 401 back if it's not present.

So I have this right now:

```
module.exports.hasAccessToken = function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.session.accessToken){
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(401).send();
  }
};
```

I am using `connect-mongo` as my store and on login I am adding an `accessToken` property to `req.session` using a value returned from an OAuth provider.

If I console log out what `req.session` is after login in I see

```
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: Tue Apr 05 2016 08:58:10 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time),
     originalMaxAge: 3000,
     httpOnly: true },
  accessToken: '<token_value_here>' }
```

When the session has expired and the 401 is being sent by my function further above I see

```
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true } }
```

`req.session` also evaluates to the above when a non logged in user visits the application. So I'm trying to find a way for me tell if the user was previously logged in and their session cookie has since expired. I was wondering if I could somehow use the browser cookies collection, but I wont be able to access the one generated by `express-session` since httpOnly is being used.

So what I would ultimately like to do is add some extra information to the response body in `res.status(401).send();` with some sort of reason code to say why the 401 is being sent, such as 'SESSION_EXPIRED', but I first need to figure out a way of knowing whether the user previously had a session that's since expired.

Does this make sense, and is this achievable?

Thanks

Comment: you could set a cookie and check it whether its a new user of existing apart for session id you can assign user another id which cant be reproduced by new user

Comment: Sorry, can you expand on this comment, I don't quite follow you. I am adding an `accessToken` property to the session cookie object after a user logs in. Are you saying to set an additional cookie, so a new one along side the one `express-session` generates?

Comment: yes generate another id that is set in another cookie that would allow you to identify if the user has previously signed in before or not and set max age to null so it never expires. set this cookie after the user has signed in. but do not you this cookie for any other purpose as that may not be safe